# Make list of administrators easy to find on Teams

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

In Charcoal's Team, I am writing a post to try to tell the mods to do something. Looking around at the users page, I noticed that, unlike on real Stack Exchange sites, there isn't a [moderators tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). **It'd be nice to have an administrators tab on the users page in Teams, or at least to have some indication of who is an admin when putting in names to ask specific people.**

Comment: The assumed workflow is for companies, isn't it?  So that'd imply then that there is an existing hierarchy who would be identified as moderators external to the actual tool they're using.

Comment: @Makoto I guess, but making it easier to find the accounts would be nice.

Comment: For starters, there are no moderators on Teams. There are _administrators_. Their duty is less about moderation and more about administration. They work on things like billing, adding removing users, setting the theme, and so on, which should be done on the corporate side of affairs rather than on the Teams end. Administrators do not have much additional moderation privileges on Teams apart from probably adding tag synonyms and viewing deleted posts, both of which are used very rarely on Teams.

Comment: What is this "Charcoal's Team" you speak of?

Comment: @PeterMortensen https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq that are running [Smoke detector](https://charcoal-se.org/) have a [team channel](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/03/stack-overflow-for-teams-is-now-available/) called Charcoal.

Answer (score 4):

On the Users page, we now have a tab to filter by Admins.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/c/[TEAM NAME]/users?tab=admins
```